# How to tell if player is 2 grid squares away from enemy

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

### Simple Game Problems

#### Part 1

I am writing a simple JavaScript game ( simple to play, not necessarily to code for me ).

I need to figure out if the Dragon is 2 moves away (or less) from the player. The Dragon can move diagonally.

So in my image, **D1** is NOT two moves away, however, **D2** IS two moves away.

I think I am making this more difficult than it actually is.

```
var player = {
    x: 4,
    y: 2
}

var dragon1 = {
    x: 1,
    y: 3
}

var dragon2 = {
    x: 6,
    y: 3
}

function isTwoMovesAway(player, dragon){

    // I JUST DON'T KNOW HOW TO MATHEMATICALLY
    // FIGURE THIS OUT because sometimes I end
    // end up with a negative number.
    
    xDiff = player.x - dragon.x;
    yDiff = player.y - dragon.y;

    numSquaresAway = [ insert your magic here ];

    return (numSquaresAway<=2) ? true: false; 

}
```

#### Part 2

The second part of this problem is, how do I figure out what square the Dragon should move to if he is pursuing the player? I want the Dragon to take the shortest route.

```
function moveDragon(){
    pX = player.x;
    pY = player.y;
    dX = dragon1.x;
    dY = dragon1.y;

    // In this case, I would expect the Dragon to move
    // to either 2,2 or 2,3
    // Is this just a matter of adding to X ??

    Dragon1.x = [ YOUR MATH HERE ];
    Dragon1.y = [ YOUR MATH HERE ];
}
```

Thanks for looking. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: Grid Question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to figure out if the Dragon is 2 moves away (or less) from the player

You can look at it this way: if it's more than 2 moves away, then either the X coordinates differ by 3+, or the Y coordinates differ by 3+, or both do. Or, both differences must be 2 or less. So the function can be:

```
function isTwoMovesAway(player, dragon){
  return Math.abs(player.x - dragon.x) <= 2 && Math.abs(player.y - dragon.y) <= 2;
}
```

> how do I figure out what square the Dragon should move to if he is pursuing the player?

Identify which direction going from the dragon's coordinate to the player's coordinate is: greater, less, or the same. If greater, add 1; if less, subtract 1; if the same, add 0. Do this for both X and Y coordinates.

```
function moveDragon(){
  const xDiff = player.x > dragon.x
    ? 1
    : player.x < dragon.x
      ? -1
      : 0;
  const yDiff = player.y > dragon.y
    ? 1
    : player.y < dragon.y
      ? -1
      : 0;
  dragon.x += xDiff;
  dragon.y += yDiff;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect. The syntax of the moveDragon function caught me a little off guard, I had no clue you could chain like that. Nice!